# Change the number formatting for a TextBox control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, regional-settings

I want the numbers appears in my own language when the user puts them in a control like a text box.

Comment: Simple WinForms control.

Comment: Khan, C# does not have controls. ASP.NET, WinForms, SilverLight  and WPF all have (different) TextBox controls.

Comment: +1 He says "Simple Winforms control" means it is WinForms TextBox control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok please go through below link...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.71).aspx

and for step by step go through below link... but this will only give you idea how to setup localization... others will be your logic...

[http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/net30/article.php/c15411__1/Localizing-Windows-Forms-Application.htm][1]

Answer (score 1):

You can try Localization concept and make resources files for all the languages you want then you call keydown event and if its desktop application this would be simple. But if its Web Apps then you have to use AJAX to set your language.
I think you want as it is in Google? right? When you select language then if you type you language will shown in text box.

Comment: Will you please explain more!What to do in keydown event?